# How to restore data from Google Drive?

Tags: backup, data-recovery, restore, google-drive, google-backup

My Samsung Galaxy SGH-T99 broke recently. I can see the backup of my data on Google Drive. I will not repair the device and want to restore my data. How can I do that? Please provide guidance.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Google should ideally offer you to restore a cloud backup when you set up a new device using the same Google account. Works well on my Nokia phones. I do not know if Samsung as a varied implementation.